# How to Play a video in windows ce wtih C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, compact-framework2.0

How to Play a video in windows ce wtih C# code
Hi every one I'am working on new poket PC application on the symbol device wiht visual studio 2005 C# and i need to play a vedio with my application 
How can i do this
please any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

If it's Windows Mobile (and your post indicates it is, though the tags do not), the easiest way is to just host the Media Player ActiveX control.  [There's an MSDN article that explains it in detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx).

Comment: what the name of that Media Player ActiveX control, Because I try to use "msdxm.ocx" but I found difficulty in understanding the OCX classes

Comment: Take a look at the article.  You run `AxImp.exe` against `wmp.dll` to get three output files (though I think they're also included in the article source).